# bad URI(is not URI?): 'redis://redis.xxx.ng.0001.apse1.cache.amazonaws.com:6379/1' URI::InvalidURIError Rails with aws redis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, sidekiq, amazon-ecs, amazon-elasticache

I am experiencing a strange issue from Passenger docker ruby 2.3 with aws redis:

```
bad URI(is not URI?): 'redis://redis.xxx.ng.0001.apse1.cache.amazonaws.com:6379/1' (URI::InvalidURIError)
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/uri/rfc3986_parser.rb:67:in `split'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/uri/rfc3986_parser.rb:73:in `parse'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/uri/common.rb:227:in `parse'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/gems/sidekiq-5.2.7/lib/sidekiq/redis_connection.rb:97:in `log_info'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/gems/sidekiq-5.2.7/lib/sidekiq/redis_connection.rb:31:in `create'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/gems/sidekiq-5.2.7/lib/sidekiq.rb:126:in `redis_pool'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/gems/sidekiq-5.2.7/lib/sidekiq.rb:94:in `redis'
```

My sidekiq config:

```
# ENV['REDIS_URL']= redis://redis.xxx.ng.0001.apse1.cache.amazonaws.com:6379/1
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = { url: ENV['REDIS_URL'] }
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = { url: ENV['REDIS_URL'] }
end
```

However if I run:

docker exec -it container_id bash

and then rails console everything seems to work just fine.

I also tried this:

```
redis_url = ENV['REDIS_URL']

# The statement below parsed successfully thus the redis_url is correct
uri = URI.parse(redis_url)

redis_options = {
  host: uri.host,
  port: 6379,
  db: uri.path[1..-1]
}

Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = redis_options
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = redis_options
end
```

But it raised the exact same error. I could run the docker locally connected to local redis just fine. I am wondering there might be something wrong with the ENV['REDIS_URL'] value.

Is there anyone experiencing this issue or any clues?

My env is 
- passenger-docker ruby 2.3.8
- aws elastic cache redis: 5.0.5
- sidekiq 5.2.7

[image]

Comment: This may seem like a dumb question have you checked the endpoint in the management console it looks malformed to me. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/Endpoints.html

Comment: @DavidWebster malformed?  can you point me out? I was testing with ECS with aws redis. it was working just fine then I tried a new docker as it raised the issue with redis by then I modified and deleted redis many time to see different settings.

Comment: It's probably a bug in the URI parser in Ruby 2.3.8.  Try running the following in Ruby 2.3.8 and 2.5.0 (a later version): `URI.parse('redis://redis.xxx.ng.0001.apse1.cache.amazonaws.com:6379/1')`.  I can't reproduce any issue with that statement in version 2.5.0.  I don't have version 2.3.8 to check this.

Comment: @PeterO. it parse without any issue at all.

Answer (score 0):

After many hours, I just realize that the redis_url from the container was pointed to the deleted Redis cluster in aws. My first launch of Redis was set to default to r5 16GM instance type which is very big and costly for testing. I decided to launch a new one with just t2 small and deleted the r5 one to save some money, however in passenger-config I have the REDIS_URL set and Nginx overridden the env value over the one I set in the ECS task.

The error raised by ruby Redis is not straightforward and having two places to set ENV (in Nginx config and in ECS-task ) make the debugging painful.